# rails 5 "bin/test" missing

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to execute the

```
bin/test
```

command mentioned at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html
but I'm getting

```
$ ./bin/test
-bash: ./bin/test: No such file or directory
```

Whats up?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I was following the same tutorial as you and the problem was that the command from the tutorial was not generating a `bin` folder.

This command

```
rails plugin new yaffle
```

Was generating a different rails plugin structure to the tutorial

I found that I was on an older version of rails and when I ran `rails -v`, I was on version 4.2

So I had to make sure I had latest version of rails installed before generating the plugin

```
gem install rails -v 5.1.3
rails plugin new yaffle
```

Comment: file bin/test had exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is only there for rails plugins created with the command

```
$ rails plugin new yaffle
```

You should read the docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html for normal Rails applications.